# How to Merge Custom Hook Providers but keep their useCases seperate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I've been creating some custom hooks and I'm wondering if I could combine their context `Providers`.

I have something like this:

`HookA`

```
const ContextA = createContext({ value })

export const ProviderA = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ContextA.Provider value={{ myVal: 'A' }}>
      {children}
    </ContextA.Provider>
  )
}

export const useA = () => {
  const { myVal } = useContext(ContextA)
  return { myVal }
}
```

`HookB`

```
const ContextB = createContext({ value })

export const ProviderB = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ContextB.Provider value={{ myVal: 'B' }}>
      {children}
    </ContextB.Provider>
  )
}

export const useB = () => {
  const { myVal } = useContext(ContextB)
  return { myVal }
}
```

Currently in order to use these hooks in components I have to wrap the app in the provider like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ProviderA>
    <ProviderB>
      <App />
    </ProviderB>
  </ProviderA>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Is it possible for me to combine these some way like creating a `CustomHooksProvider` that acts are the provider for both hooks but keeps allowing me to `useA` and `useB` as I have been doing?

Something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomHooksProvider>
    <App />
  </CustomHooksProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

What would my `CustomHooksProvider` component have to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `CustomHooksProvider` component the accepts `children`, and renders both providers:

```
const CustomHooksProvider = ({ children }) => (
  <ProviderA>
    <ProviderB>
      {children}
    </ProviderB>
  </ProviderA>,
);
```

A more generic approach would be a function that takes a list of wrappers components, and generate a new component that accepts children, and renders the children inside the wrappers:

```
const wrapWith = (...wrappers) => ({ children }) => 
  wrappers.reduceRight((rendered, Component) => (
    <Component>
      {rendered}
    </Component>
  ), children);
```

And then you can generate the `CustomHooksProvider` by calling the `wrapWith` function with your providers:

```
const CustomHooksProvider = wrapWith(ProviderA, ProviderB);
```

Demo:

```js
const { createContext, useContext } = React;

const wrapWith = (...wrappers) => ({ children }) => 
  wrappers.reduceRight((rendered, Component) => (
    <Component>
    {rendered}
    </Component>
  ), children);

const ContextA = createContext({ value: '' })

const ProviderA = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ContextA.Provider value={{ myVal: 'A' }}>
      {children}
    </ContextA.Provider>
  )
}

const useA = () => {
  const { myVal } = useContext(ContextA)
  return { myVal }
}

const ContextB = createContext({ value: '' })

const ProviderB = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ContextB.Provider value={{ myVal: 'B' }}>
      {children}
    </ContextB.Provider>
  )
}

const useB = () => {
  const { myVal } = useContext(ContextB)
  return { myVal }
}

// generate the combined provider
const CustomHooksProvider = wrapWith(ProviderA, ProviderB);

const App = () => {
  const { myVal: a } = useA();
  const { myVal: b } = useB();
  
  return (
    <div>
      {a}
      {b}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomHooksProvider>
    <App />
  </CustomHooksProvider>,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  It's just what I was looking for, actually started coding that straight after asking the question haha. Defining the question really helped :)

Comment: Yep. It jumps at your from the question :)

Comment: I've added a generic reusable approach. See if it works for you.